# ios8 UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl doesn't work properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

Under ios 8 using presentViewController modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl disappear all page.
I want it to work like ios 7.

Comment: Did you find a fix for this. I have same issue.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Any solution?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I applied this fix, it worked for me on iOS 8 and Xcode 6.

```
    [_mapToolbarController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl];
    [self presentViewController:_mapToolbarController animated:YES completion:^{
        [_mapToolbarController.view.superview addSubview:self.view];
    }];
```

Obviously, _mapToolbarController will be the controller that you want to present. To see why you'd need this, add a breakpoint at the line in the completion handler. Do the animation, and you'll see in the completion handler that the curling animation had just finished and everything was perfectly fine. For some reason that I can't explain, in iOS 8 you'll need to tell the iOS framework to "keep" the curled view and make sure it doesn't get thrown away. The code in the completion handler tries to "keep" the soon-to-be-faded curled view onto the screen. Note that in this context, self.view is the view that is being curled.

Comment: I tried this in iOS8 and Xcode 7.2.1: while it looks great the new controller's controls no longer work. It seems the controls in self.view are still active.

Comment: @ghr Do you mean this worked for you in iOS 8 but not in iOS 9 now?

Comment: @ghr I have an app on the app store built with iOS 8 that uses this trick. However, I haven't tried it with iOS 9 yet.

Comment: I mean I tried it in iOS8 (eight) and Xcode 7.2.1 and it does not work either in the simulator or on a device. I tried a number of variations on 16 March, the day I came across your suggestion.

Comment: @ghr I'm nots sure why it didn't work for you. Do you want to pose a new question for it? My answer at least worked for me.

Comment: This is the only thing that actually works for me as of iOS 12. However, one thing I had to do was disable user interaction on the previous view. Now I'm just trying to figure out how to detect when a user dismisses the modal by tapping on the page curl so I can re-enable user interaction.

Answer (score -1):

You can always try to make your own transitions with iOS 7. Have a look [HERE](http://www.objc.io/issue-5/view-controller-transitions.html)

Comment: It should be Apple's job for the animation that it's supposed to be supported.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I am not proud of the fix I came up with but it works just fine and took me little time to do it.

I managed to get a screen shot of the page curl at the stage that I wanted it to remain. It took a few tries but I got it. Then I took that image into Pixelmator and cropped it to just the page curl portion, made everything else transparent, smudged out the extraneous artifacts like the battery indicator, signal bars and time.

I imported that image in 320, 640 and 960 widths then insert it at the top of my presented view at load time. It came out virtually perfect. I cannot tell the difference from what I had before. Works exactly as I wanted it.