# UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl not working on iOS 8

Tags: ios, ios7, model-view-controller, ios8

I have the code that works absolutely fine with iOS7 and below versions. 
But with xcode6 and iOS8 UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl is not working. page curl dismisses in fraction of second as view appears.

```
MyViewController* opts = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithView:someView];
opts.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
opts.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;
[self presentViewController:opts animated:YES completion:nil];
```

[Edit] - I found that if build is done xCode5.1 and run on iOS8 this works as expected. Something wrong with xCode6 and iOS8 build?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25927199/ios8-uimodaltransitionstylepartialcurl-doesnt-work-properly Looks to be same problem. No answer on that one too.

Comment: http://www.openradar.me/18305611

Answer (score 1):

Copied from the first link in the comment (my solution in that post).

I had the same issue and I applied this fix, it worked for me on iOS 8 and Xcode 6.

```
    [_mapToolbarController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl];
    [self presentViewController:_mapToolbarController animated:YES completion:^{
        [_mapToolbarController.view.superview addSubview:self.view];
    }];
```

Obviously, _mapToolbarController will be the controller that you want to present. To see why you'd need this, add a breakpoint at the line in the completion handler. Do the animation, and you'll see in the completion handler that the curling animation had just finished and everything was perfectly fine. For some reason that I can't explain, in iOS 8 you'll need to tell the iOS framework to "keep" the curled view and make sure it doesn't get thrown away. The code in the completion handler tries to "keep" the soon-to-be-faded curled view onto the screen. Note that in this context, self.view is the view that is being curled.

Comment: This will not work with UINavigationController classes. I am getting an exception saying that child view controller should have parent controller X but parent is Y. Where X is my view controller to be presented and Y is custom navigation controller class.

Comment: While I can't guarantee it works for everybody I m simply sharing a potential hint. If you can find a way to keep the view in your own implementation like what I did to myself it might work.