# UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl disappear on iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8, uimodaltransitionstyle

I am trying to present my ViewController with UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl transition. I am using the following code

```
PuzzleViewController *vc = [[PuzzleViewController alloc] init];
vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;
vc.puzzleImage = imageView.image;
[self.navigationController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl work fine with iOS 7, like this

[image]

But for iOS 8, the visual part of the previous view on top disappear, so the user can't understand that he can click on the top left corner to back to previous view.

[image]

So is there a way to fix this on iOS 8?

Comment: Getting the navigation controller to present the VC seems a bit odd, what if you get the VC the code is in to present it instead?

Comment: You mean what if I do like this to present the VC?

[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];

I tried it but still the same problem.

Comment: Looking at some other posts, this seems to be an issue with Xcode 6, if done in Xcode 5 it works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27596762/uimodaltransitionstylepartialcurl-not-working-on-ios-8

Comment: Did you found any solution for it? I am also facing same problem..

Comment: unfortunately not yet

Comment: possible duplicate of [ios8 UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl doesn't work properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25927199/ios8-uimodaltransitionstylepartialcurl-doesnt-work-properly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is broken in iOS 8 and Xcode 6. Here is the Radar for it: http://www.openradar.me/18305611

This ticket was closed as a duplicate and I can't find the other, but it's there.

Comment: Yeah I checked that, it's a boring bug honestly.
Thanks anyway.

Comment: Do we have any news on this?

Comment: No, I changed the way of presenting the ViewController